# Last function that gets called in a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I want to assign a textbox value to a variable in the last method that gets called in a viewcontroller.How?

Comment: Last method called before what?

Comment: last method while loading or unloading?

Answer (score 3):

it's `viewDidUnload` i guess. or you may also do this in `viewDidDisappear`, `viewWillDisappear`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are asking, you are looking for either `viewDidLoad`, `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, or `didEnterForeground`/`Background`. Take a look at those methods and see which one fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to implement the UITextFieldDelegate for you text field and set your variable in `textFieldDidEndEditing:`

Answer (score 0):

This method is get called at last in view controller.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear {

     // In this you can set your text box value.
}
```

Hope this will help you.